# SQL oracle: Display records that are not found in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried to fetch a record that will return me with the doctor's ID and the total number of all the prescriptions they have given.

```
SELECT doc.DID, COUNT(pr.DID)
FROM DOCTOR doc, PRESCRIPTION pr
WHERE doc.DID = pr.DID
GROUP BY doc.DID;
```

By using this statement, I am able to receive the information as long as there is at least one prescription made by a doctor. This is how my results looks like

```
DID                  COUNT(PR.DID)                                              
-------------------- -------------                                              
3292848                          1                                              
3292885                         10                                              
3293063                         10                                              
3332949                         15                                              
3332950                          2
```

But I want it to display such that even doctors that has not prescribed before will be shown in the record with a count of 0

```
DID                  COUNT(PR.DID)                                              
-------------------- -------------                                              
3292848                          1                                              
3292885                         10 
3293042                          0               
3293063                         10                                              
3332949                         15                                              
3332950                          2
334021                           0
```

Comment: the join should be `left join`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please avoid using old join syntax. Use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Now here you need a `LEFT JOIN` which would give you everything from first table and matching records from second table. For non matching records, you will get `null`, which you can utilize in `where` or `select` clause.

```
SELECT doc.DID, COUNT(pr.DID)
FROM DOCTOR doc
left join
PRESCRIPTION pr
on doc.DID = pr.DID
GROUP BY doc.DID;
```

Comment: `count(pr.DID)` would suffice..with what you have currently, the results would be incorrect as `null`s would be counted too.

Comment: Thanks! I also realized that it would give `1` for non matching records. Thanks for pointing out.